# How can I get some chunks come from what flow using mitmproxy?

Tags: mitmproxy

I am building web proxy using the following `mitmproxy`.
https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy

I want to scan streaming body and pass them to client.
`mitmproxy` already has the similar feature; https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/mitmproxy/addons/streambodies.py

I implemented the following code.

```py
def responseheaders(self, flow):
    flow.response.stream = self.response_stream

def response_stream(self, chunks):
    for chunk in chunks:
        if not my_function(chunk):
            raise Exception('catch')
         yield chunk
```

In my above code, there is no way to catch some chunks come from whose flow when `my_function` returns `False`.

i want to get from what flow some chunks come in flow.response.stream feature.

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly in that you are trying to view the actual streamed data (such as a camera live stream) in the response?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question with the following code.

```py
from functools import partial

def responseheaders(self, flow):
    flow.response.stream = partial(self.response_stream, flow=flow)

def response_stream(self, chunks, flow):
    for chunk in chunks:
        yield chunk
```

Otherwise, using `__call__` in object could be one of solutions.

```py
class Streamer:
    def __init__(self, flow):
        self.flow = flow

    def __call__(self, chunks):
        for chunk in chunks:
            yield chunk


def responseheaders(self, flow):
    flow.response.stream = Streamer(flow)
```